# APK Expansion Files downloading not working

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to Download my already uploaded resource to Google play store on Android device, but resource could be download and throws me "download failed because resources could not be found" error.

I had twice check my API key - Package name and versioning info,
I have already refered [This](http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html) , Also I am using expansion with Login to Google account in Android device.

Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: did u solve this problem? how?

Comment: @chelo_c Yes, For now we need to upload all the data on expansion and then we need to live the app in market , you can just put in Beta or Alpha version , But without live it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question so that others can get benefit, I have resolved my problem by contacting Google support, As per there reply we only can use Expansion files feature after publish-Beta testing-Alpha testing , we can use in DRAFT mode as per new update.

So now anyone can use expansion  except Draft mode.

Comment: Hello, Kirit, i am getting same error, can you explain in detail please. or post answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865804/apk-expansion-issue-download-failed-because-the-resources-could-not-be-found-an/23866001?noredirect=1#comment36734869_23866001

Comment: Yes, For now we need to upload all the data on expansion and then we need to live the app in market , you can just put in Beta or Alpha version , But without live it will not work