# apk expansion issue- Download failed because the resources could not be found android

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

i am using apk expansion file which have approx 250 MB resource. before few days it was working fine. but now i facing one critical issue with apk expansion file.

it will give always `**Download failed because the resources could not be found**`

and also i am getting warning in log cat

```
I/LicenseChecker(12165): Binding to licensing service.
I/LicenseChecker(12165): Calling checkLicense on service for XXXXX
I/LicenseChecker(12165): Start monitoring timeout.
I/LicenseChecker(12165): Received response.
I/LicenseChecker(12165): Clearing timeout.
```

> i have set correct file bytes and public key and .obb name also.

**is there any policy change by google for apk expansion ?**

does anybody have idea regarding this issue please replay.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am answering my own question so that others can get benefit, I have resolved my problem by contacting Google support, As per there reply we only can use Expansion files feature after publish-Beta testing-Alpha testing , we can use in DRAFT mode as per new update.

So now anyone can use expansion except Draft mode.

And in Your You need to remove signature licecning code before Expansion dwonloading stasrts
Also make sure your SHA key and your application should not be in Draft

I have remove below code from my app

```
try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
         "my pkg name",
        /// android.test.purchased
         PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
         md.update(signature.toByteArray());

         Base64.DEFAULT));
         Base64.DEFAULT));
         }
         } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

         }
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for replay. Can you tell from where i have remove "licencing code" are you talking about Public key of application which is set on expanstion downloader activity?

Comment: public key is required

Comment: okey then can you tell me please what you said to remove " signature licecning code" ?

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

Buddy to download `Expansion File` from `Google Server` we must have to **Login with any Google Account in Device**, 
Otherwise `Expansion File` will **not Start Downloading**...

**OR**

While your Application is getting Published ( Time between you pressing publish and it actually going live on Google Play ) the `Expansion Files` are **Unavailable**...

Comment: yes, Login is available for Google play in device.App is not publish in Google play, i have save it in draft for testing purpose.

Comment: i think it is not compulsory to publish app on Google play for testing apk expansion right ?

Comment: dear, i am waiting since last two days.. :)

Comment: Yes, i am testing app in real tablets not in emulator.

Comment: Buddy just want to confirm that your device is having proper internet connection available...