# Expansion file error, "Download failed because the resources could not be found."

Tags: android, download, expansion

Basically:
For a few days we are trying to download an expansion file for our apk.
But it keeps saying "Download failed because the resources could not be found."
While debugging, we found that the responseCode in LicenseValidator.verify is ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED.

Is there anyone having the same problems?

Steps taken so far:

- App added to Google Play's developer account in "draft". Also added 1 Expansion file.
- Uploaded a couple of days ago.
- Saved, not published.
- main.1.our.package.name.obb created with Zip. Files are not compressed, just stored.
- Also created obb file by using JOBB.
- AndroidManifest.xml: versionCode=1, added all permissions from guide.
- Copied license code from console to Service script (provided by android SDK)
- fileSize is set in bytes (336467473L) appr. 328 MB.
- Google play accounts on test devices are set to correct developer account.
- Enough free space on devices. Restart hardware and software many times.
- Time of devices are not in the future.
- Cleared cache and local files of Google play App and Installed app.
- Several ways of running and installing the apk file by:

  1. Running apk directly from Eclipse.
  2. Export and sign apk in Eclipse and install it manually on devices.
  3. Use adb to install apk on device (signed and unsigned apk)
- Signing is done by keytool.
- Used zipalign to align the apk file.
- Test devices are Galaxy Tab 10.1 (4.0.4), Galaxy Tabpro 10.1 (4.4.2)
- Allow installation of apps from unknown sources is checked on device

Comment: Duplicate: [apk expansion issue- Download failed because the resources could not be found android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23865804/456814).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixt! After publishing an alpha release in Google play's developer console and waiting a few ours the download started...